# How can I force the driver to click on a pop up on a page which has not completed loading

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using java with selenium IEDriverServer. I would like to know if is possible to click on a pop up on a page which has not completed loading. When I get the pop up, my code is not running until I click on Ok on pop up.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to click on element that is not visible.

But you can add the following config, it will tell the driver to implicitly wait for elements:

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned `if is possible to click on a pop up` I presume it's a **`JavaScript Popup`**.

Essentially, until & unless the synchronous/asynchronous **`JavaScript`**/**`AJAX Calls`** gets executed completely the `Page Loading` won't be complete. Hence, invoking `click()` method while `Page Loading` may not fetch optimum results.